# Where is the definition of MetricsGetter.GetTextWidth

Tags: openxml-powertools

I am trying to use the [Open-XML-Powertools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools).

I have downloaded the current version from GitHub and I am copying a lot of code from the sample file
*Open-Xml-PowerTools-vNext\OpenXmlPowerTools\WmlToHtmlConverter.cs*

However, in application I am actually using the nuget package OpenXmlPowerTools **Version 4.5.3.2**, which is marked as the latest stable version.

Part of this code uses the method **MetricsGetter.GetTextWidth**:

```
var w = MetricsGetter.GetTextWidth(ff, fs, sz, runText);
```

However, this method is not present in the version of MetricsGetter in the nuget package.

Short term I can copy the source code of this function into my application, so will not be a big problem, but which version is up to date?

Is the code in GitHub newer than the code in the nuget package?
Or older?
Is there an alternative method which I should use with the nuget package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the NuGet package is very much outdated. Thus, the best approach is to:

- fork (optionally) and clone EricWhiteDev's [Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) repository,
- build the `OpenXmlPowerTools.dll` assembly from source,
- put that assembly into a `libs` folder (or whatever you use), and
- reference that assembly in your projects.

The previously official [OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) repository has been archived.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, in fact I have decided that Open-Xml-Power-Tools is not the best option for my application, but it's good to have clarity.